# Why does using the ternary operator to return a string generate considerably different code from returning in an equivalent if/else block?

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization

I was playing with the Compiler Explorer and I stumbled upon an interesting behavior with the ternary operator when using something like this:

```
std::string get_string(bool b)
{
    return b ? "Hello" : "Stack-overflow";
}
```

The compiler generated code for this (clang trunk, with -O3) is this:

```
get_string[abi:cxx11](bool):                 # @get_string[abi:cxx11](bool)
        push    r15
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     ecx, offset .L.str
        mov     eax, offset .L.str.1
        test    esi, esi
        cmovne  rax, rcx
        add     rdi, 16 #< Why is the compiler storing the length of the string
        mov     qword ptr [rbx], rdi
        xor     sil, 1
        movzx   ecx, sil
        lea     r15, [rcx + 8*rcx]
        lea     r14, [rcx + 8*rcx]
        add     r14, 5 #< I also think this is the length of "Hello" (but not sure)
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     rdx, r14
        call    memcpy #< Why is there a call to memcpy
        mov     qword ptr [rbx + 8], r14
        mov     byte ptr [rbx + r15 + 21], 0
        mov     rax, rbx
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        pop     r15
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Hello"

.L.str.1:
        .asciz  "Stack-Overflow"
```

However, the compiler generated code for the following snippet is considerably smaller and with no calls to `memcpy`, and does not care about knowing the length of both strings at the same time. There are 2 different labels that it jumps to

```
std::string better_string(bool b)
{
    if (b)
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Stack-Overflow";
    }
}
```

The compiler generated code for the above snippet (clang trunk with -O3) is this:

```
better_string[abi:cxx11](bool):              # @better_string[abi:cxx11](bool)
        mov     rax, rdi
        lea     rcx, [rdi + 16]
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rcx
        test    sil, sil
        je      .LBB0_2
        mov     dword ptr [rcx], 1819043144
        mov     word ptr [rcx + 4], 111
        mov     ecx, 5
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 8], rcx
        ret
.LBB0_2:
        movabs  rdx, 8606216600190023247
        mov     qword ptr [rcx + 6], rdx
        movabs  rdx, 8525082558887720019
        mov     qword ptr [rcx], rdx
        mov     byte ptr [rax + 30], 0
        mov     ecx, 14
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 8], rcx
        ret
```

The same result is when I use the ternary operator with:

```
std::string get_string(bool b)
{
    return b ? std::string("Hello") : std::string("Stack-Overflow");
}
```

I would like to know why the ternary operator in the first example generates that compiler code. I believe that the culprit lies within the `const char[]`.

P.S: GCC does calls to `strlen` in the first example but Clang doesn't.

Link to the Compiler Explorer example: https://godbolt.org/z/Exqs6G

Thank you for your time!

*sorry for the wall of code*

Comment: the result type of the ternary is `const char*` while the strings individually are `const char[N]`s, presumably the compiler could optimize the latter much more

Comment: @kmdreko: the compiler still knows that it's a `const char*` pointing to one of two possible known-constant string literals.  That's why clang is able to avoid the `strlen` in the branchless version.  (GCC misses that optimization).  Even clang's branchless version is not well optimized; significantly better would have been possible, e.g. 2x cmov to select between constants, and maybe a `cmov` to select an offset to store at.  (So both versions can do 2 partially-overlapping 8-byte stores, writing either 8 or 14 bytes of data, including trailing zeros.)  That's better than calling memcpy.

Comment: Or since it's loading constants from memory anyway, use SSE2 `movdqa` loads and turn the boolean into a vector mask to select between them.  (This optimization relies on the compiler knowing it's safe to always store 16 bytes into the retval object, even though the C++ source probably leaves some trailing bytes unwritten.  Inventing writes is generally a big no-no for compilers because of thread safety.)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The overarching difference here is that the first version is **branchless**.

16 isn’t the length of any string here (the longer one, with NUL, is only 15 bytes long); it’s an **offset** into the return object (whose address is passed in RDI to support RVO), used to indicate that the small-string optimization is in use (note the lack of allocation).  The lengths are 5 or 5+1+8 stored in R14, which is stored in the `std::string` as well as passed to `memcpy` (along with a pointer chosen by CMOVNE) to load the actual string bytes.

The other version has an obvious branch (although part of the `std::string` construction has been hoisted above it) and actually does have 5 and 14 explicitly, but is obfuscated by the fact that the string bytes have been included as immediate values (expressed as integers) of various sizes.

As for *why* these three equivalent functions produce two different versions of the generated code, all I can offer is that optimizers are iterative and **heuristic** algorithms; they don’t reliably find the same “best” assembly independently of their starting point.

Comment: Notably, in this case, one should note that memory writes are much trickier to optimize -- even when `memcpy` is an intrinsic internally the optimizer still needs to reason about the potential side-effects of a write occurring sooner or later. In the first snippet, the ternary expression is evaluated and _then_ a write happens, in the second, the write happens as part of the evaluation of the ternary expression.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Since the parameter can’t be aliased, the order doesn’t matter—but it’s true that the optimizer’s analysis might be affected by that consideration.

Comment: I agree, it _shouldn't_, but as you mention since optimizers are iterative and heuristic, ... it's not too surprising that it does :)

Comment: Being branchless is a red herring here. Juergen's answer is the correct one. The difference is the type on which the selection is performed (`std::string` vs. `char*`), and whether a constructor needs to be called with the result of the selection or not.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica: Being branchless is simply a description of the resulting assembly in one case (which is helpful for understanding the other differences).  The constructor is entirely inlined (“evaluated at compile time”) in all cases here; the type of the return statement’s operand is in no way a constraint on the generated code (since no address of any string literal escapes).

Comment: If the compiler were able to perform the constant value propagation analysis to its bitter end, it should generate the exact same output in all three cases. But it doesn't. So, apparently, it didn't finish that analysis. And obviously it's thrown off by the fact that it has to construct a single object with one of two possible arguments in the first case, while it needs to select the construction of two different objects in the other cases. The comparison between the behavior of the first and last code examples is instructive.

Answer (score 13):

The first version returns a string object which is initialized with a not-constant expression yielding one of the string literals, so the constructor is run as for any other variable string object, thus the memcpy to do the initialization.

The other variants return either one string object initialized with a string literal or another string object initialized with another string literal, both of which can be optimized to a string object constructed from a constant expression where no memcpy is needed.

So the real answer is: the first version operates the ?: operator on char[] expressions before initializing the objects and the other versions on the string objects already being initialized.

It does not matter whether one of the versions is branchless.

Comment: No `memcpy` was truly needed in the branchless asm either; this is a missed optimization vs. using more `cmov` instructions on immediate operands, or SSE2 compare.  You answer does explain why the source led the compiler in the direction it went, though; compilers are far from perfect.

Comment: Note that in the OP's Godbolt link with all 3 versions uncommented, https://godbolt.org/z/597Kzd, `return b ? std::string("Hello") : std::string("Stack-Overflow");` compiles to a branch with GCC and clang (same as the `if` version), despite the chance for constant-propagation to make const `string` objects.